# Why is tar creating file size 10240 and how to export exact part of file name to variable?

Tags: tar, wget

I'm using wget to recursively fetch directories filed with files. There are many folders and files in it. I'm downloading all directories recursively too. Sometime-somehow wget "stuck" and don't download whole directory. For example you have 3 directories (dir1, dir2, dir3) all filed with files e.g. (file1, file2, file3). Problem is sometime WHOLE dir 2 don't get download but dir 1 and dir 3 are downloaded successfully. It is pretty random. I noticed it because after downloading I create tar with one directory and when i don't have that dir downloaded, tar create empty tar with file size "10240".

I'm trying to make a script to download all missing directories and make tar with them. I'm trying it by:

`ls -la | grep -w "10240"`
and after that i should somehow export just part of the tar file name because that file name consist of parameters with which I can specify exact link do re-download missing directory. Is it possible to extract just some part of file name in variable ?

PS: Also it could be problem with making .tar. I don't understand why tar is creating tar file with size "10240".

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to use the exit code of `wget` and repeat the command in case of failure?

Comment: For such questions always provide a complete example. You mention the tar file name consists of parameters. Add the output of `ls -l` for all files and directories involved.

Comment: Try a second run with `wget --mirror`?

Comment: 1024 bytes is the default record size for tar archives.

Comment: tar was originally a tape archiver, and some of its characteristics derive from restrictions in that medium. In particular, many tape media use cyclic correction checks which only work with a maximum of 512 bytes, and need to write or read multiple blocks to achieve transfer speeds. So the minimum size of a tar archive is actually 10240 bytes (20 * 512). Unused blocks are zero-padded and permitted in the specification. Such an archive may contain no files (under special conditions), a single small file, or a small number of tiny files.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant a record on a real tape is not a multiple of anything. 1024 bytes is the native record size and a tape device would support 1111 bytes as record size if this was requested. A typical record size in former times was e.g. 800 bytes (10 punching cards).

Comment: @schily The 9-track 1/2" tapes with vacuum tensioning I used in the 60s and 70s would write any block size you wanted, but the interblock gaps were a fixed size, so small blocks wasted a lot of the tape, and they only did parity detection. The QIC streamers in the 80s (IIRC) used error correction (CRC or Hamming), and the SCSI drive controllers managed the physical blocking. If you did transfers that didn't suit it, you ended up either writing padding blocks, or backspacing the tape, both highly suboptimal for performance. (ftp.gnu.org › Manuals › tar › html_node › tar_132)

Comment: @Paul_Pedant QIC drives are not compatible to classic tape drives since they only support 512 byte block size. Modern SCSI tape drives again are compatible to classic tape drives. BTW: I do not care about the GNU tar documentation, my tar implementation was already 5 years old when SUG tar, the implementation that has been adopted by GNU started to exist and my tar implementation is the first one that was able to keep the tape streaming...so believe me, I know what I am talking about.

Comment: @schily So exactly why does GNU tar have a minimum archive size of 10240 bytes, and is it necessary for it to be so?

Comment: @Paul_Pedant There is no need for this limitation. BTW: `star` implements the option `-P` since 1985 in order to make the last record partial. This grants to hit EOF when reading from QIC tapes without knowing what block size was used for writing and this even works for real tapes since real tapes permit to have a different record size for each record.